# two variable functions with positive laplacian

Tags: differential-geometry

The function  $f(x,y)=x^3+y-1$ in $\omega = (1,2)^2$ is such that $f\times \Delta f \ge 0$ on $\omega.$ I am wondering about the existence of a $C^2-$extension $F$ of $f$ in $\Omega = (0,2)^2$ such that $f\times \Delta f \ge 0$ on $\Omega$.

Thanks

Comment: 6 questions, 0 accepted answers, last seen August 20. Typical ask-and-run.

Answer (score 0):

This particular function can be written as $f(x,y)=(x^3-1/2)+(y-1/2)$ where both summands are 1-variable functions that are convex and strictly positive on $(1,2)$. It is not hard to extend such functions to $(0,2)$ (or the entire line $\mathbb R$, if you wish) while keeping both convexity and positivity. (And of course, convexity implies subharmonicity).

Here is a concrete extension to $\Omega$, using the [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket): $$f(x,y)=\left((x^3-1/2)+10(1-x)^3[x<1]\right)+\left((y-1/2)+(1-y)^3[y<1]\right)$$
You can check directly that both expressions in big parentheses are positive on $(0,1)$. Convexity is clear, as is $C^2$ smoothness.